# The Google-Login with Socialite doesn't work when i push my Laravel PHP application on Heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, laravel-socialite

I have an Laravel/PHP application with Google-Login from Socialite. It works fine on localhost. But when i push it on Heroku the Google-Login gets an error after I selected the account which I want to log in. So I think something with the callback is wrong. The google id, secret and redirect are already in Config Vars on Heroku.I also added the right auth-url on google's api.
What else could be wrong?

Comment: what error did you get? can you share

Comment: Please make sure the google callback url is correct in your env file and in your google development account.

Comment: I get "500 Server Error" my callback url is correct on google development and i added the google redirect on heroku - settings - config vars since the env file doesn't get uploaded with pushing

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this has any effect or not but it worked in my case when I changed APP_NAME in .env to the same as apk name when registering api